# How to display output of command in python

Tags: shell, command, python-3.3

I want to run the command df -h to display disk information, But when i run my code nothing is displayed in the terminal, I even tried to do "df -h > out.txt" and then cat out.txt but that didn't work either.

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess


def main():
    os.system('clear')
    print("Options: \n")
    print("1 - Show disk info")
    print("2 - Quit \n")
    selection = input('> ')
    if selection == 1:
        subprocess.call(['df -h'], shell=True)
    elif selection == 2:
        sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading user input with `input()` returns a string. However, your `if/elif` statement are comparing the contents of `selection` with integers, so the comparison will always be `False`. As a workaround, use this:

```
selection = int(input('> '))
if selection == 1:
   ...
```

Comment: no worries, we've all done it. This is why interactive development is so important - running `type(selection)` or even `print(selection)` would show you what you need to know.